# Htaccess rewrite url (Shorten url)

Tags: .htaccess

So I have the url: myurl.com/projects/url/visit.php?link=fbehe and I want to rewrite it as so:

myurl.com/u/fbehe

But it isn't working. I am using this so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/u/([^/]*)$ visit.php?link=$1 [L]
```

I would also like to note that I placed my htaccess file in the directory with my visit.php file. so myurl.com/projects/url/.htaccess

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Which are the variables strings in this URL: `myurl.com/u/fbehe`? `fbehe` is the value of `link`, but what about `u`?

Comment: u is just a fake directory. If that cannot be done myurl.com/fbehe would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/u/([^/]+)/?$    [NC]
RewriteRule .*       projects/url/visit.php?link=%1 [L]
```

Maps silently

`http://myurl.com/u/anyvalue` with or without trailing slash

To

`http://myurl.com/projects/url/visit.php?link=anyvalue`

Comment: Is there any way so that it only works via myurl.com/u/anyvalue I don't really want it to work with anything other than that.

Comment: It works, but I can still do other folders such as myurl.com/burger/fbehe. I only want it to work through myurl.com/u/fbehe. Is that possible? Thanks for the help so far though :)

Comment: Yes, I want it to only work by accessing myurl.com/u/linkname

Answer (score 0):

Try using NC as well. Also, not sure if the absolute path is working. Try a relative if the .htaccess is in the root of your website.

```
RewriteRule ^/u/([^/]*)$ visit.php?link=$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score -1):

do you use any framework of this? maybe u can you there functionality like routes. can rewrite your url..

Like Codeigniter,Cake

They have routes to change the url like that.