# URL Shortening: What is the cheapest option to create customized shortened URL?

Tags: javascript, web, frontend, url-parameters, url-shortener

I am working on a product, where I am showing some 'n' number of jobs on a webpage. Now, I want to shorten the url's and show shortened & customized url's to the user. I did some google search and found that there are lot of service providers like bitly who provide you that service.

Here's what I want to do :

My URL : http://www.helloworld.com/show?companyName=xyz&jobId=123

To:

URL1 : http://someShortenedURL/xyz/123

or

URL2: http://someShortenedURL/companyName=xyz&jobId=123

It's just that I want to retain the company and jobID information in my URL after I shorten the link. I know bitly does it. But we need to buy their service for that. Is it any cheaper way to do it or any other service which is cheaper and/or better than bitly?

Thanks.

Comment: The cheapest way to have customized urls the way you want is it to do it yourself. I made one for my personal use, it's just a database containing all the links, that redirects you. On a short domain name. Nothing more. And if you already have a server, you can link your short domain name to it and only have the cost of the domain name as extra.

Comment: Thanks @Blex.  

Lets say I buy a short domain abc.ly, and I want to make it customized url.  
1. I build a server(hosting space)       
2. Host a application which takes in requests for urls.  
3. When the request comes in, it generates some shortened_url using the customized input provided and some algorithm.  
4. Once the url is ready, enter it as a map entry into the data base.   
  
Now next time when the user clicks the shortened link,  the request abc.ly/helloCompany get the mapEntry and return it to the user.   
  
is this approach somewhat correct?

Comment: That's exactly it. And as you can imagine, accessing a link that does not lead to a real path will generate a 404 error, so in order to avoid that, you'll need to redirect these URLs to your parsing script, using URL rewriting. Learn about `.htaccess` files and check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14311660/htaccess-rewrite-url-shorten-url

Comment: Thank you very much Blex. Your comment really helped me a lot.